# How to get captcha from response from VK API?

Tags: python, exception, captcha, vk, vk-sdk

I have a script in Python that helps me to post some notes in VK. But sometimes my script needs to solve captcha. I have following code:

```
vk = vkontakte.API(token=token)
response = vk.wall.repost(object = link)
```

As I understand, if I need to solve captcha, VK API raises exception. But, I couldn't find any examples for it. Problem is that I can't get `captcha_sid` and `captcha_img` from it.

Or maybe you know how can I get response in JSON format, not as exception ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access vk api via http requests. For doing this you need access_token, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912670/spring-social-vk-vkontakte-how-to-fetch-user-photo-albums/31915379#31915379) how to get it if you dont have it already.

Then you way will be very easy by link

```
https://api.vk.com/method/wall.repost?object=WALL_OBJECT_HERE&group_id=TARGET_GROUP_ID&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If repost done successfully, you will see response like this:

```
{"response":{"success":1,"post_id":676,"reposts_count":3,"likes_count":11}}
```

But if you need to solve captcha response will be like this:

```
{"error":{"error_code":14,"error_msg":"Captcha needed","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"wall.repost"},{"key":"object","value":"your_object_here"},{"key":"group_id","value":"56983001"}],"captcha_sid":"381041951450","captcha_img":"http:\/\/api.vk.com\/captcha.php?sid=381041951450&s=1"}}
```

Now you can easily get captcha sid and captcha_img link, download it, solve and repeat request upper just with adding 2 parameters to it: `captcha_key=YOUR_SOLVED_CAPTCHA&captcha_sid=SID_YOU_GOT`

Success :)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the last stable version of vkapi

However, in the old ones when you receive VKError, the `captcha_img` and `captcha_sid` are keys to `.error`, not to the `Exception` itself:

```
except vkerror as e:
    captcha_img = e.error['captcha_img']
    captcha_sid = e.error['captcha_sid']
```

Just make sure you've defined the right Error:

```
vkapi = vk.API(access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
vkerror = vk.api.VkAPIMethodError  # not vk.API (still it has the same Exception in it)
```