# Spring social vk (Vkontakte): How to fetch user photo albums

Tags: spring-social, vk

im trying to integrate some spring social projects into my project and now im searching for a way how to get users photo albums from vk/vkontakte.
Getting the profile photo data is no problem as i can get it with the VKontakteProfile class.
As the api https://vk.com/pages?oid=-17680044&p=getProfiles offers such function i was searching a api method but couldn't find...

Answer (score 1):

To get user albums you must have an access_token because typically most uf users hide their albums from not autorized people. You can get it by making OAuth-autorization with app created by you OR by this link:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username=YOUT_ACCOUNTS_LOGIN&password=YOUR_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD
```

This link uses by official vk android application to make "**straight**" autorization. **Straight** auth is allowed only to official apps like ios, android and windows phone app. So `client_id` and `client_secret` is data from android-application. It was extracted from decompiled app. Do not afraid: it will not be changed ever.

So, you made this GET request and got `access_token` in response if login data is correct.

Then you should use method `photos.getAlbums` like this:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getAlbums.xml?owner_id=YOUR_PAGE_ID&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

As you can see, url contains "`.xml`". So if you want response to have JSON format just remove "`.xml`" from this url. But xml is more comfortable to parse I think.

Next if you need to get albums photo later you should use method photos.get. To use it you need albums identification numbers. In response of your last request this parameter is called "aid".
[image]

You can use regular expressions to grab these parameters from response, expression should be `<aid>(.*?)<\/aid>`

So next you making your request to get data from specific album:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get.xml?owner_id=YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID&album_id=PARSED_ALBUM_ID&access_token=YOUT_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The same situation with "xml" response format. So you will see the list of objects "photo" which contains all data about this picture like it's ID in album, it's link on pictures (with different sizes), it's width, height, description, upload date and others.

Feel free to get any help about VK API from me.

The list of all methods that API has is here: https://vk.com/dev/methods

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, VK provides API for getting user albums.

`photos.getAlbums` API method stands for this function.

For example,
https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getAlbums/?owner_id=5369654&access_token=your_access_token

It works for me. Read more about it here:
https://vk.com/dev.php?method=methods#/dev/photos.getAlbums

Comment: Oh. Now I see. You need exactly the way to work with it using Spring. Still, probably, this answer can help you. Please, inform me if it does not - I will remove it.

Comment: Thanks Yeldar. I know that vk offers this api method (see also the link in my original question). As im using the spring social vkontake project from the site http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/ im looking now for a api method in this library. I dont really want to build my own json requests to fetch only the album informations if there is a library like this :)

Comment: Ups sorry....just saw i posted the profile link. I was meaning the album link of course...